# How to set up Androidpn

Tags: android, push-notification

Androidpn is a open source project which provide push service to android, it is a xmpp based server and a client tool kit.
I'm totally a newbie for this, could some one help me on how to set up this server, is it possible to do that using google app engine? and what should i do.
Thank you very much!